# Internet router is in a different subnet

Tags: routing

The network 192.168.195.0/24 isn't mine and it's full of pcs, but it has the router 192.168.195.1 which connects to internet.
Now, I have to create the network 192.168.59.0/24 and i must connect it to the internet.
I have a linux box with 2 eth .
I may do forwarding, but then the computer in the different subnets can communicate and i don't want that. I just want to connect 192.168.59.0 to internet.
Should i use nat? Which commands should i use?

Comment: Yeow, forgive me, that's my first question, the setup is regarding business, i know that the question isn`t clear but i will try to improve! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want computers on the two nets communicating, firewall that kind of the traffic on the box that routes between the two nets. NAT would only protect the machines on 192.168.59.0/24 from being contacted by the machines on 192.168.195.0/24, but not the other way around. But unless the router on 192.168.195.1 knows what to do with traffic from/to 192.168.59.0/24, you should set up NAT.

As for which commands to use that depends on the OS.

Comment: well I can setup any OS, i would like to install debian.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the computer as a router and make it the default router for the devices in the 192.168.59.0/24 network. Configure a DHCP server to issue machines dynamic IP addresses, if desired. It should NAT for those machines. It's default gateway should be the 192.168.195.1 router that has the Internet connection.

To prevent machines on the subnets from communicating, just use a firewall rule. Disallow packets on the interface in the 192.168.59.0/24 network whose destination address is in the 192.168.195.0/24 network. Communication in the other direction shouldn't be possible, but if you're paranoid, add a similar rule on the other interface to block traffic in the other direction.